# Crystal reports 11 Page header

Tags: crystal-reports

i have 4 page headers in crystal report 11. in one of the page header has sub report. i have a problem, when sub report data has more than one page. 
the reports are not displaying properly. please help me to correct it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you give us some more information? How is it not displaying properly? What error messages are you getting?  Screenshots would help too.

Answer (score 1):

In your sub-report, if you don't want the header to repeat, go into the Section format settings for the sub-report and either turn them off completely or make it conditional with something like:

If PageNumber > 1 then
   True
Else
   False

(The True is for Suppress; false would mean Don't Suppress)